# Why do they take the natural log of the integration constant in solving this differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am taking a circuits class. My book is solving a first order differential equation for a RC circuit. Here are the steps they take:

[image]

in the second step, after integrating, they end up with lnA as the integration constant. Where does that come from?

Comment: If $K$ is your constant of integration, you can write it as $K=\ln(A)$, where $A=e^K$. Nothing special here, it's just so when you subtract it from both sides you get a more convenient term $\ln\frac{\nu}{A}$ on the left.

Comment: The constant can be anything, and for any specific problem the constant will be a fixed value; however, any number is the (natural) log of some other number, and so we can write the constant as $ln A$ for some number $A$.  Why do we do this?  Because it makes solving the resulting equation a bit easier and the resulting formula nicer (Try solving it with $K$ instead of $ln A$ and compare the results)

Comment: Imagine you used $B$ instead of $\ln A$ as the integration constant. (Which itself comes from the fact that derivation eats constants for breakfast.)
Then you'd have $v(t) = e^B e^{-t/RC}$. So it doesn't matter, as $ln$ is a surjection from $\mathbb R_{> 0}$ to $\mathbb R$, that is you can write every real number $B$ as $B = \ln A$, where $A$ is some positive real number.

Comment: Ah ok. Perfect. @BenWest if you will add your comment as an answer I will accept it since you were first .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the sake of an answer,

If $K$ is your constant of integration, you can write it as $K=\ln(A)$, where $A=e^K$. Nothing special here, it's just so when you subtract it from both sides you get a more convenient term $\ln\frac{\nu}{A}$ on the left.